# How to fix 504 error caused by a plugin in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I get a 504 error when I want to access the admin dashboard in my client website. I've contacted technical support in siteground and he told me that the error caused by a plugin, and he was right. When I desactivate the plugin, I can enter the dashboard again.

How can I fix this problem since there are **no errors or warnings**, I checked my PHP logs, and it just shows me a PHP Notice:

> **Trying to get property of non-object** in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4056

```
public function is_singular( $post_types = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $post_types ) || ! $this->is_singular ) {
        return (bool) $this->is_singular;
    }

    $post_obj = $this->get_queried_object();
    //here is the error
    return in_array( $post_obj->post_type, (array) $post_types );
}
```

So, does this PHP notice make a timeout error? or there is another reason?
Any advice?

Comment: there's your clue, you already got it from the error logs. start debugging. do you have a programming background? maybe you need to hire a web developer to help you.

Comment: you mean the PHP notice caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for people to help you. 504 error, is a timeout, meaning that the plugin you are using doing something on the background for too long, longer than your server timeout is set, usually 30 seconds.

We don't know plugin you are using, but if it do something with large amounts of posts, pages, images or products.. like preparing them in a specific order, format or similar, this is likely the cause.

Just to give you an example, a plugin that do Product filters often run multiple loops to format everything in a certain way before it could be used, but if you have 10.000+ products and a slow/low resources hosting it could easily go over 30 seconds.

Comment: You are right, cause I've imported too large business posts, but I wondered how to debug this issue when I have no errors appear, as i know php notice is just a notice means it's not cause any errors, right? would do you think if i increase the timeoutis that help?

Comment: the 504 error do appear in the error log, but it wont show the part of the code that overheads. Because the code might be working, just either poorly optimised or not meant to work with low timeout time. Increasing the timeout will help. But if this plugin does the its "thing" every time someone visits your website, then, no matter how much you increase your time, its poorly optimised.

If its a one-time run (or once a week/month) then you can increase timeout, and make sure your hosting is run on php 7.2 as its much, much faster than 5.6 and php 7.0 and can execute code lightning fast.